# Eloquent update doesn't work in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update a field after submitting in the following form:

```
   <form action="{{ route("comments.update") }}" method="post">

                @csrf

                <input type="hidden" name="commentIDToEdit" id="commentID">
                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                    <label for="toEditComment"></label>
                    <textarea name="toEditCommentary" id="toEditComment" cols="3" rows="5" style="resize: none"
                              class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Modificar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I have the CommentsController, where I process the data from the form. Here is the code:

```
    public function updateComment()
{

    request()->validate([
        "toEditCommentary" => "min:10|max:500"
    ]);

    if (Session::has("username") && getWarningCount(User::whereUsername(session("username"))->value("email")) > 0) {

        Caveat::where("commentID", request("commentIDtoEdit"))
            ->update(["updatedComment" => request("toEditCommentary")]);

    } else {
        die("No se cumple la condición");
    }

    if (Comment::where("commentID", request("commentIDToEdit"))->exists()) {
        Comment::where("commentID", request("commentIDToEdit"))
            ->update(["commentary" => request("toEditCommentary")]);
    }

    return back();

}
```

Curiosly, the comment is updated in his table, but not the warning. I was thinking in the fillable property in the model, but I don't have it, instead this, I have the following code:

```
protected $guarded = [];
const UPDATED_AT = null;
const CREATED_AT = null;
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @A.ANoman The field doesn't update

Comment: This is post method. So where is your `$request->all()`

Comment: `the comment is updated in his table, but not the warning` what `warning` is that?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Sorry. The warning refers to Caveat table

Comment: Then your logic `if (Session::has("username") && getWarningCount(User::whereUsername(session("username"))->value("email")) > 0)` is not triggering

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I used dd() to know what contains the input named commentIDToEdit and it was null, and now, changing the name, the comment doesn't update

Comment: replace `<input type="hidden" name="commentIDToEdit" id="commentID">` by `<input type="hidden" name="commentIDToEdit" id="{{ $comment->id }}">`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Is a problem if the form is in a modal? Because I think I cannot take laravel variables from a modal

Comment: No problem - as long as `$comment` is passed on to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hidden input is named `commentIDToEdit`, but in the Controller you fetch the Caveat using `request("commentIDtoEdit")` (different case).

**What you wrote:**

```
Caveat::where("commentID", request("commentIDtoEdit"))
```

**What you should have done:** (note the different casing)

```
Caveat::where("commentID", request("commentIDToEdit"))
```

This is because in the view, the input `name` is `commentIDToEdit`, not `commentIDtoEdit`.

Comment: I was trying to compare the Caveat's column named commentID with request("commentIDtoEdit"). Is not correct this way?

Comment: I further expanded my explanation